# ListView subitems and columns

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a problem where when I add a subitem to the listview all the subitems go out to each of the columns, what I am trying to do is have 4 columns with the results going vertically down each column, I am going to post the code I am using for 1 of the columns so as not to have too much crap on the page here.

```
    Dim source As String = (New Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://arma.newagerp.com/bb.php")

    ListView1.Columns.Add("Deaths")

    Dim formula2 As String = "<td><div class='deaths'>([^<]*)</td></div>"

    Dim item2 As New ListViewItem("item2", 1)

    For Each item As Match In (New Regex(formula2)).Matches(source)
        item2.SubItems.Add(item.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {item2})
```

if you want more code just tell me but this is working and its just the same for the other 3, the other 3 are just player names, score and time in the same listview.

Comment: a) RegEx for parsing HTML is (still) ill advised b) i cant see any "time" field in the source c) you need an outer loop to parse player with an inner loop to add subitems parsed from Score and Deaths (and time if it is elsewhere).  d) at least the AddRange part of your code probably doesnt do what you want

Comment: Sorry you have lost me I am quite new to vb.net and I dont think I have got that far in learning it, could you provide an example with the code I have provided.

Comment: for starts your code is going to add the literal "`<td><div class='deaths'>1</td></div>`" for the death subitem as opposed to the value in that td element, is that what you want?  might that be the source of `the subitems go out to each of the columns`?  is it just that your columns need to be resized ?

Comment: Try using CsQuery. Very compact syntax, easy to understand and maintain: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery, would be smth like `htmlpage.cq("div .deaths").Text` (your formula2 is malformed, did you notice it btw?)

Answer (score 0):

If i undrstand your question right, you want to add next row after passing the value to all four column? if this is right then have a look example code below.

```
While (Condition) 
Dim objItem As ListViewItem
            objItem = lv_Details.Items.Add("")
            With objItem
                .SubItems.Add("")
                .SubItems.Add("")
                .SubItems.Add("")
                .SubItems.Add("")
            End With
End While
```

Hope this will help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you give me it in the code I provided, I dont understand where to put it, I am quite new to vb.net